# Retrieve Attachment from Mailgun Form Post PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, attachment, mailgun

How do i retrieve and save the attachment sent to me via a form post with Mailgun's POST

The following the some of the parameters

```
attachment-1    
{:filename=>"crabby.gif", :type=>"image/gif", :name=>"attachment-1", :tempfile=>#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140707-2-slsrkh>, :head=>"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment-1\"; filename=\"crabby.gif\"\r\nContent-Type: image/gif\r\nContent-Length: 2785\r\n"}

attachment-2    
{:filename=>"attached_файл.txt", :type=>"text/plain", :name=>"attachment-2", :tempfile=>#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140707-2-sudxuf>, :head=>"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment-2\"; filename=\"attached_файл.txt\"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nContent-Length: 32\r\n"}

Content-Type    
multipart/mixed; boundary="------------020601070403020003080006"
```

Answer (score 8):

So I know this is a year late, but I had the same problem and figured out how to download the attachments. The files in the post are in stored in the environmental variable [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php). The information for each file will look something like:

```
Array
(
    [attachment-1] => Array
        (
            [name] => ATextFile.txt
            [type] => text/plain
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php8zhmlU
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 70144
        )
)
```

The path to the file is stored in `tmp_name`, so in this case, `/tmp/php8zhmlU` is the full path to the file. `move_uploaded_file` will overwrite any existing files! To download all the attachments from the `POST` I wrote a function:

```
function download_attachments($pathToDownloadDirectory)
{
    foreach($_FILES as $file)
    {
        if($file['error'] == "0")
        {
            if(!(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $pathToDownloadDirectory . $file['name'])))
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }    
    }
    return 1;
}

download_attachments("/Full/Path/To/Some/Dir/");
```

Documentation for this top can be [found here.](https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-receiving.html#supported-actions-for-routes)

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit, perhaps with some sample code. I am having the same issue

Comment: referencing mailgun documentation here, https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-receiving.html#supported-actions-for-routes

Comment: adding a more detailed reference about attachments https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html?highlight=attachment#routes

Comment: I believe the question is around Mailgun's API post, not PHP in general.

Answer (score 4):

1. use store action from route session in order to obtain information
   about your email. ([retrieving stored message](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#retrieving-stored-messages)
2. json_decode "attachments" property in order to obtain information
   about your attachments
3. get api key and use php library in order to use get api.

if you json decoded list of attachments is $files, you can do

```
$mgClient = new Mailgun('yourApiKey');

foreach ($files as $file){
    file_put_contents($file->name,$mgClient->get($file->url)->http_response_body);    
}
```

to download every attachment